# Button font properties ignored when customizing button content

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I got the following setup:

```
<Button x:Name="DeleteFilter" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Padding="2">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Height="9" Width="9" Stretch="Fill" Margin="5 3">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_delete}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Text="{Resx DeleteFilter}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

However, when launching my application I get the following result which is not what I want. All font properties seem to be ignored when I set the `Content` property of my button manually.

Live example:

[image]

I'd like to have the same fontstyle and fontsize as the right button. I tried to specify the style manually by using `StaticResource` and `DynamicResource` as follows:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MetroButton}"....
```

but nothing changed.

I guess that I need to implement a style which overrides the existing one and transfers the formatting to the `TextBlock` element but I have no clue how to do that.

---

The working "LOAD FILTERS" button in the right:

```
<Button x:Name="LoadFilter" Content="{Resx LoadFilters}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

MahApps.Metro's standard button (MetroButton) is included in [this](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Buttons.xaml) file.

The style I applied to my icon button:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="MetroIconButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Height="9" Width="9" Margin="5 3" Stretch="Fill">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: You must either be mistaken, or not describing your problem adequately. If you set the `FontFamily` property on the `Button` either inline, or in an applied `Style`, it will affect the `TextBlock` in the `Content`. If yours doesn't, then please edit your code example to actually show a working example of your problem.

Comment: @Sheridan That's what I thought but somehow that is not working. See my update for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup the StackPanel is used as a content which is not so ideal, you may create a style containing the template and the required property setters for font so it remain consistent for the desired buttons across the application.

So if I try to create a button style for you that would be

```
<Style x:Key="MetroButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Rectangle Height="9" Width="9" Margin="5 3" Stretch="Fill">
                      <Rectangle.Fill>
                          <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                      </Rectangle.Fill>
                  </Rectangle>
                  <ContentPresenter/>
              </StackPanel>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

then I would use this style on button as

```
<Button Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource MetroButton}" Tag="{StaticResource appbar_delete}"/>
```

**Update**
leveraging the ContentTemplate to achieve the same while utilizing the existing template.

```
 <Style x:Key="MetroIconButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Rectangle Height="9" Width="9" Margin="5 3" Stretch="Fill">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}"/>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

usage remain quite same except the style `MetroIconButton`

```
<Button Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource MetroIconButton}" Tag="{StaticResource appbar_delete}"/>
```

I am using `Tag` property to hold the icon so it is plug and play for you, but better is to use Attached properties for the same. `l:ExtraProperties.Icon={StaticResource appbar_delete}"`, I can provide a sample if you need that too.

Actually in previous style we override the Template defined in the MetroButton style so it failed. After looking at the original implementation of MetroButton style I come up with the ContentTemplate way to actieve the same. So instead of setting Template we will set the content template which will be picked up by MetroButton style and applied to the content.

**Using Attached Properties**

declare a class inheriting DependencyObject or any of its derived class along with the desired property as mentioned below

```
class ExtraProperties: DependencyObject
{
    public static Visual GetIcon(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Visual)obj.GetValue(IconProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIcon(DependencyObject obj, Visual value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IconProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Icon.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Icon", typeof(Visual), typeof(ExtraProperties), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

add namespace to your xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Example">
```

then change the style as

```
<VisualBrush Visual="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}, Path=(l:ExtraProperties.Icon)}"/>
```

and usage as

```
<Button Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource MetroIconButton}" l:ExtraProperties.Icon="{StaticResource appbar_delete}"/>
```

using Attached properties is more WPF approach, instead of hacking other properties which may not be guaranteed to behave as expected.

Comment: The problem is that `MetroButton` is the style base (as you might see in my picture in the question, the right button) and I want my button to inherit the style so that it looks exactly like the right one... just with the small icon. I applied your style (thanks) to my button and added a `BasedOn` property but the inheritance fails somehow.

Comment: Is it possible to have a look on the original MetroButton Style? Is there any specific error when you specify BasedOn? These would help us to implement the appropriate style with added Icon.

Comment: Yes, see my update in the question. There's a link pointing to the file where the original MetroButton is implemented. And no, I get no errors. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I find what you actually mean by failed style, see updated answer.

Comment: That's it, works perfectly. Thank you very much. Yeah, I tried to implement an attached property but I don't know where the property comes into play. May you edit a short (really short) example how to include the property in the xaml? Do I also need to include that in the style or just in the button that is using the style? e.g. something like `<Button Content="blabalba" Icon="{Static....>`. Oh and another short question: Why was setting the StackPanel without a style not ideal? Why did it not work? Just curious...

Comment: Updated my answer for attached properties. Secondly when you directly add content which is StackPanel in this case, you are getting away from DRY (do not repeat yourself) principle, as next time when you need same behavior on other button you'll have to repeat all the code you applied on the first and become difficult to maintain when you need to change the style. Such modifications become easy with style as need to modify a single place only. Secondly the answer to why it didn't work is complicated due to n number of reasons, so we may need to debug to find the same.

Comment: Hm, there seems to be an error with the code of the property, I implemented everything successfuly but somehow the image is not displayed. I nearly used the same code, except of the namespaces and everything compiles with no error. :s

Comment: Nevermind, I found the error. See my edit (if it's approved). Wish I could upvote again, thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Please verify the code of visual brush, at first I wrote it incorrectly using templatedparent where correct one is using relativesource.

Comment: Nope, I used RelativeSource. The property path had to be set using the `Path` property.

Comment: That's great. Path is kind of optional, but sometimes it become deemed necessary for various reasons. I'll also include it in my examples from now onwards, so less chances of faults. Anyways I am glad that the solution worked for you.